# Calculate the rolling count using window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which contains orders of our customers:
order_date: the date of orders (which is not unique since each order may have more than one product)
customer_id: which is not unique

I want to calculate the number of orders for each customer up to the current order_date, but since there are duplicates in the order_date the results are not reasonable.

I use window functions in Postgres 11.2

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."orders" (
    "order_date" timestamp,
    "customer_id" integer
);
```

Insert for data:

```sql
INSERT INTO "public"."orders"("order_date", "customer_id") VALUES('2018-12-13 20:45:24.571964', 402) RETURNING "order_date", "customer_id";
INSERT INTO "public"."orders"("order_date", "customer_id") VALUES('2018-12-13 20:45:24.571964', 402) RETURNING "order_date", "customer_id";
INSERT INTO "public"."orders"("order_date", "customer_id") VALUES('2018-10-12 20:08:39.635959', 466) RETURNING "order_date", "customer_id";
INSERT INTO "public"."orders"("order_date", "customer_id") VALUES('2018-11-04 22:15:14.905851', 483) RETURNING "order_date", "customer_id";
INSERT INTO "public"."orders"("order_date", "customer_id") VALUES('2018-11-04 22:15:14.905851', 483) RETURNING "order_date", "customer_id";
INSERT INTO "public"."orders"("order_date", "customer_id")
```

I used this codes to generate what I want, but it does not works

```sql
select *,COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by orders.customer_id order by orders.order_date range between interval '100 years' PRECEDING AND 
       CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),0) AS 
       customer_orders_count_up_to_now,
       COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by orders.customer_id order by 
       orders.order_date asc range BETWEEN interval '7 days' PRECEDING 
       AND CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),0) AS 
       customer_orders_last_seven_days 
from orders
```

I expect the output columns for customer_orders_count_up_to_now and customer_orders_last_seven_days to be 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
but, the actuals are different due to duplicates in order_date.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you basically want `count(distinct)` as a window function.  Postgres does not (yet) support it.  But you can use `select distinct` in a subquery:

```
select o.*,
       COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by o.customer_id
                               order by o.order_date
                               range between interval '100 years' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),
                0) AS customer_orders_count_up_to_now,
       COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by o.customer_id
                               order by o.order_date asc
                               range BETWEEN interval '7 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),
                0) AS customer_orders_last_seven_days 
from (SELECT DISTINCT o.customer_id, o.order_date from orders o) o
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want for each record, it does not consider the orders in the same order_date but considers the other (when partitioned by customer_id). In fact, i do want to have all records not only distinct ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and in case others have the same problem, I shared here:

```
select *,COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by orders.customer_id order by orders.order_date range between interval '100 years' PRECEDING AND 
   CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),0) - COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by orders.customer_id,orders.order_date order by orders.order_date range between interval '100 years' PRECEDING AND 
   CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),0) AS 
   customer_orders_count_up_to_now,
   COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by orders.customer_id order by 
   orders.order_date asc range BETWEEN interval '7 days' PRECEDING 
   AND CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),0) - COALESCE(COUNT(*) OVER (partition by orders.customer_id order,orders.order_date by 
   orders.order_date asc range BETWEEN interval '7 days' PRECEDING 
   AND CURRENT ROW EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),0) AS 
   customer_orders_last_seven_days from orders
```

The idea is that, in order to remove the duplicate count from rolling count, we should subtract the count of those records which have duplication in order_time from the calculated rolling count.